# Record radio automaticly with PHP

Tags: php, cron, icecast, internet-radio

I don't know if it is possible, but i want to make a cronjobs script that checks every hour is there is a live DJ, and once it is, the script must automaticly record it. and put it on the webserver.
The radio is a icecast sevre and has a M3U and a XSPF output.
Is it possible to automaticly record it to a mp3 file and put that to a server with cronjobs and PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like to be possible

Comment: You have any idea how?

Comment: Google for example 'php m3u mp3'

Comment: nothing found that will help me

Comment: Try to use it, modify it, when you came to a dead-end come here and tell us what you have tried and what is the unexpected result

Comment: I use file_get_content witch can get the stream content with max becouse it is an end-less file so i can try to find out how to conver it in mp3